# Sobre criação de variáveis

Tags: php, zend, declaração-de-variável

Eu uso o ZEND 2 e estou no controller. Lá criei uma ação para imprimir um campo (descricao) de uma tabela (recibosaida). A questão é que quando faço ligação do controller com a view não aparece nada no site. Pelo que eu percebi eu tenho que definir o valor da variável `$saidarecibo` atribuindo a ela o valor do campo da tabela que chama descricao. Como faço isso?

Segue abaixo meu controller:

```
 public function imprecibosaidaAction() {

        $data_parametro = "";

        $saidarecibo = $descricao;

        $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);

        $saidarecibo = $this->getTable('Admin\Model\Saidarecibo')->get($id);

        //$this->view->saidarecibo = $saidarecibo;

        if ($id == 0) {
            throw new \Exception("Código obrigatório");
        }

         // Turn off the layout, i.e. only render the view script.
         $viewModel = new ViewModel();
         $viewModel->setTerminal(true);

        $view = new ViewModel(array(
            'saidarecibo' => $saidarecibo,
        ));

        //return $view;
        return $viewModel;

    }
```

Agora segue a view que criei, ela deve imprimir somente o campo da tabela:

```
<?php echo $this->saidarecibo; ?>

<a style="margin-top:10px;" href="javascript:self.print()">IMPRIMIR</a>
```

Comment: Ao que parece você está tentando ecoar uma variável de template não definida, haja vista que você definiu ela em **$viewModel**, mas retornou **$view**.

Answer (score 1):

Tens duas coisas erradas.
Uma no controller: Estás fazer `return` de uma variável diferente:

```
//estás a fazer return $viewModel; e devia ser 
return $view;
```

No action tens também o uso da variável de forma errada: Experimenta usar `$saidarecibo` em vez de `$this->saidarecibo`
No action o key do array do objecto `viewModel` define o nome da variável a usar na view.

Answer (score 0):

O correto quando se usa a saída `$viewModel->setTerminal(true);`
seria atribuir as variáveis de retorno na mesma instancia da seguinte forma:

```
$viewModel = new ViewModel();

$viewModel->setTerminal( true )->setVariables(array( 'saidarecibo' => $saidarecibo));

return $viewModel;
```